# Android Annotations sample applications crashes while trying to install in emulator

Tags: annotations, android-support-library, android-annotations

I am facing problem while trying to run the code on my emulator. Sorry i dont have 10 reputation to post the image of the logcat, so producing the logcat file as text.

```
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.annotations.Annotations: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.annotations.Annotations" on path: /data/app/com.example.annotations-1.apk
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.annotations.Annotations" on path: /data/app/com.example.annotations-1.apk
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
04-10 04:53:58.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     ... 11 more
```

Please help me where i am struck and also i am furnishing my sample code as follows

```
package com.example.annotations;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.NoTitle;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

@NoTitle
@EActivity(R.layout.main)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @ViewById(R.id.button1)
    Button btn1;
    @ViewById(R.id.textView1)
    TextView txt1;
    @ViewById(R.id.editText1)
    EditText edt1;


    @Click
    void btn1() {
        String text = edt1.getText().toString();
        txt1.setText(text);
    }
}
```

The library which i am using is androidannotations-api-2.7.jar

Comment: Can you post your Android Manifest file?  You may not be declaring the Activity properly.

Comment: First, you should update to AA 3. The stack trace tells you are missing the `com.example.annotations.Annotations` class. What is this class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem but still had no success.
Have you tried to set the "Project > Properties > Java Build Path" and set all output folders for the default output folder?

Some people said it works, not for me, but anyway it may help you.

follow my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gmail.rodoufu.moneychange"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.gmail.rodoufu.moneychange.HelloAndroidActivity_" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you import the libraries? try add your lib to  project > properties > Java Build Path > libraries .
Here is a post that may concern you.
https://code.google.com/p/androidannotations/issues/detail?id=89